# Django 2.0: NoReverseMatch at /url/ (/pledges/group/7/)

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I just have upgraded from Django 1.11 to 2.0. These are the urls I have for one Django application:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^pledge/(?P<group_id>[0-9]+)/$',
        views.pledge, name='pledge_by_group'),
    # I have more urls, but I have omitted them since they are not relevant
    url(r'^404/$', views.bad_request, name='404')
]
```

After upgrading, I checked everything was fine. Then, I changed:

```
url(r'^pledge/(?P<group_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.pledge, name='pledge_by_group')
```

to:

```
url('pledge/<int:group_id>/', views.pledge, name='pledge_by_group'),
```

in order to take advantage of [simplified URL routing syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax) in Django 2.0. However, I am getting the following error when I try to access `http://localhost:8000/pledges/group/7/`:

> NoReverseMatch at /pledges/group/7/
>   Reverse for 'pledge_by_group' with keyword arguments '{'group_id': '7'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['pledge//']

This is my view:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='')
def group_pledge(request, group_id):
    """Some docstring..."""
    # Some code that is not relevant to the problem

    context = {
        'pledge_url':  reverse('pledges:pledge_by_group',
                        kwargs={'group_id': group_id}),
    } # context has more values, but for practical reasons I don't include them

    return render(request, 'pledges/home.html', context)
```

According to the error, the problem is in this line:

```
reverse('pledges:pledge_by_group', kwargs={'group_id': group_id})
```

Can somebody tell me what is going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new syntax requires the use of [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) function. For example:

```
from django.urls import path

...
path('pledge/<group_id>/', views.pledge, name='pledge_by_group'),
```

Comment: omg, I cannot believe it, yes you are totally right. Thanks!!